# Flutter data load

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, dart

> hi i am a beginner programmer.
> I would like to load sentences in my app. Depending on which settings are activated, different sentences should appear. The sentences should be saved in the app and cannot be changed. The user cannot enter or change any sentences

Example: Sentence A (has property 1; 2, 3)
Set B (Has Property 1)
Set C (Has property 1; 3)
etc

If setting 3 is selected in the settings, a set with these properties should be selected at random (in this case set A or C). I've already programmed the settings.

Which tool or concept do I use to keep my sentences ready in the database and then query them?

Comment: Use ```bloc``` for business logic, ```moor``` for database libraries

Comment: share your code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend "[shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)"
It allows you to cache information, especially useful for projects where you need to store little information.

I leave you two examples (setter and getter) that can be adapted according to your need:

```
import 'package: shared_preferences / shared_preferences.dart';  

Future <String> getVariable ({required String variable_name}) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance ();
    return prefs.getString (variable_name) ?? "";   
}

  Future <bool> setVariable ({required String variable_name, required String value}) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance ();
    return await prefs.setString (variable_name, variable_name);   
}
```

Note: **prefs.** supports setDouble, setBool, setInt and setStringList, so the possibilities are left to your imagination.

If you still consider that your project requires a database, then the [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) plugin is the best.

I hope I was helpful, keep going and good luck